# Android Screen Size Support

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I need to develop my app with multiple screen size support.
 I recently watched youtube tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8dGQEN9sRs
In the video it demonstrates how to create a new android.xml file and select the option for size and it automatically chooses a screen display size for graphic layout in the xml. 
My problem is when I try to do the same as in the video, eclipse does not select an appropriately sized screen in the graphic layout. Is there any known reason why this is happening? Thank you

Also if you know of any tutorial on screen size support that are extremely straight forward it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on developr.android.com has good explanation on supporting multiple screen sizes.

Comment: This web page was actually everything I needed to see. Thanks